# What does it mean to give a div a style='height:100%'?

Tags: html, css

There's lots of questions on SO related to this, but the ones I scanned are all for detailed specific situations.  What I want to know is, at a conceptual level, what does it mean to say:

```
<div style='height:100%'>
```

How high is 100%?  100% of what?

[EDIT]

Followup question: If 100% represents the height of the parent, but the parent is <body> and has no height other than the height of the div, then what does it mean?  It seems recursively defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

100% of the parent container's height.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/6VRn6/

If you want to use this method to make the div 100% of the page's height, you have to specify the height as 100% of the body and html as well.

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

When you don't specify a `html` or `body` height, their heights are the sum of the heights of the elements in it.

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6VRn6/3/) showing this. We have a 200px div with 2px borders totaling 204px and then a 40px status div. The `body` height should be 244px. Now, if you add the CSS above to the page, the height will be the height of the bottom right quadrant of the jsfiddle. Try adding it and running the code again. Then resize the result pane and run it again to see the height change accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

100% of the `offsetParent`. In most cases, that's the document. It can also be an element with `position` other than `static`, or a component of a table.

Comment: How high is the document, then, having not been otherwise specified, and assuming a bunch of random elements are inside the div?  Does the 100% not mean anything?

Comment: I would guess that it would be the height of the window when the page loads, but I wouldn't know for sure. I don't use such dubious CSS ;)

Comment: @ScottStafford The height of `body` will be the height of the elements in it. In my example (in my solution), I have a box with 2px border. `$("body").height()` returns `204` (200px + 2px * 2 for top/bottom)

Comment: @sachleen: So basically the 100% on the div is meaningless, then.  Which makes sense.

Comment: In that sense, yes, since the height of body will be just the height of the div. But if you specify a height for `body` then it can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The height:100% means :
     Make that div big as the parent!

Answer (score 0):

It just means 100% of the **`div`** or **`class`** or **`tag`** it is enclosed within. Try having an idea somewhat this:

`{--parent loop
    {
    ..height 100% of above loop
    ..
    }
}`